# Real projective space and the stereographic projection

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, stereographic-projections, compactification

What is the relationship between the real projective plane $\mathbb RP^2$ and the stereographic projection i.e. a plane $\mathbb C$ with a point at infinity $\infty$,
i.e. a one point compactification of the complex plane $\mathbb C$?
Are there some natural maps between these two spaces?

Comment: Mapping the Euclidean portion of the plane, i.e. without the elements at infinity, is kind of an obvious map. Mapping any point on the line at infinity to the single point at infinity is a well-defined operation, so going from $\mathbb{RP}^2$ to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is a well-defined operation for points, while the opposite is ambiguous and algebraically maps the point at infinity to the null vector describing an undefined result.